# Clarification on Trigonometric Notation

Tags: trigonometry

Consider the following terms:

$cos5x$ and $sin^2x$

Are these terms equivalent to:

$5cosx$ and $(sinx)^2$

If not please explain. If so please confirm.

Thanks

Comment: ${\sin ^2}(x) = {(\sin x)^2}$ -- yes, but $\cos 5x \ne 5\cos x$. Writing ${\sin ^2}(x) = {(\sin x)^2}$ is just a convention adopted a long time ago.

Comment: They aren't statements, they are terms, and, no, they are not equivalent (the ones with cosine), as you can tell by substituting in, say, $x=1$, and evaluating on a calculator.

Comment: They are actually statements because $\cos 5x$ and ${\sin ^2}(x)$ is a statement declaring that the cosine function and the sine function have such and such properties, but we usually think of them as terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The first $\cos 5x$ means $\cos(5x)$, while $\sin^2x$ means $(\sin x)^2$.

The parentheses are omitted in the first case as the argument $5x$ is understood.  The square is placed after the $\sin$ but before the $x$ so as to differentiate $\sin(x^2)$ from $(\sin x)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

No! for the first one, you can take $x = \pi /5$, then $\cos(5x) = -1$ while $5\cos(x) = 0.9$. The second however are equivalent!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that there are *traditional* ways of writing arguments and powers in connection with trigonometric functions. Always adding parentheses would probably be helpful, especially for beginners.

Thus (with "$\ne$" here meaning "not equal *in general"*)
$$\sin^2x = (\sin(x))^2 \ne \sin(x^2)\text{ and }\ne\sin(\sin(x))$$
(though there are areas where the latter would be the preferred interpretation).

By the same writing traditions,
$$\cos 5x = \cos(5x)\ne \cos(5)\cdot x$$
(and even more so $\ne5\cdot\cos(x)$ as checked by plugging in appropriate values for $x$).
Beware however that one would always read
$$\sin x\cos x=\sin(x)\cdot\cos(x)\ne \sin(x\cdot\cos(x)).$$